# Android Spoon output shows generic AVD names

Tags: android, spoon

I have implemented Spoon and so far it looks great. However my AVD's show up in the output as "***Unknown Android SDK built for x86***" instead of the AVD name. My real device shows up properly.

Is there a setting available either in Spoon or when creating the AVD's that will show the real AVD names instead of "***Unknown Android SDK built for x86***"

The first picture shows what my AVDs are called in the AVD Manager

[image]

Second picture shows what my AVDs are called in the Spoon output. Note that the top device listed is my physical device and not an AVD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could customize your filename to include more specific details about your device you are testing/grabbing screenshots

Typically one calls

```
Spoon.screenshot(context,fileName)
```

in order to take screenshots

You could customize the filename to be constructed in this fashion

```
String manufacturer = Build.MANUFACTURER;
String brand        = Build.BRAND;
String product      = Build.PRODUCT;
String model        = Build.MODEL;
String osVersion    = Build.VERSION;

StringBuilder fileNameBuilder = new StringBuilder();
fileNameBuilder.append(manufacturer );
fileNameBuilder.append("-");
fileNameBuilder.append(brand );
fileNameBuilder.append("-");
fileNameBuilder.append(product);
fileNameBuilder.append("-");
fileNameBuilder.append(model);
fileNameBuilder.append("-");
fileNameBuilder.append(osVersion);
fileNameBuilder.append("-");
fileNameBuilder.append(String.ValueOf(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()));
String filename = fileNameBuilder.toString().replaceAll("\\s","").replaceAll(".","_");//filename hates spaces and dots
```

You could also look into https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames
for more human friendly names